# Making predictions with support vector classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, notation

I am reading this [book](http://smlbook.org/book/sml-book-draft-latest.pdf) (chapter 8.3 - 8.5) about SVM's, while also trying to work with the `ksvm()` function from the `kernlab` package in `r`.

While fitting a model is fairly straightforward, I don't know how to derive the method 8.3 prediction step on page 174, namely manually computing the linear combination needed for classification of a datapoint. Equation 8.35c states $\hat{y}(x_{*}) = sign(\hat{\alpha}^\top K(X,x_{*}))$.

I suppose this might be an equally relevant question to ask on stackoverflow about the `r` part, but I struggle to translate the mathematical notation into a "real" problem, so I decided to post it here instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What is it about equation 8.35c that you'd like help with?

Comment: I need help understanding what the different components represent in an example.